# sending and receiving data using AS3 and facebook apprequests

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, apprequests

I'm working on a facebook app in flash with AS3, using the facebook graph API. At times, I'm sending apprequests to users and I need to include some data in the request, to be used if the user clicks on it and runs the app.

My request code so far is this:

```
var fbReq:Object = new Object();
fbReq.message='Play with me!';
fbReq.title='You were invited to play a game!';
fbReq.to=sendTo;
fbReq.data = {test: "testingData"};

Facebook.ui('apprequests',fbReq,inviteResult,'iframe');
```

According to what I could find online, the data object should be added as URL params when my app loads, but I can't see those anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to what I could find online, the data object should be added as URL params when my app loads

I don’t know what gave you that idea – but it’s just not true.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/:

> *data: Optional, additional data you may pass for tracking. **This will be stored as part of the request objects created**.*

So you have to read the request object, using the request ID that is passed to your app.